# Possible JQuery functions to use

Tags: jquery

I am currently working on a website which has a fixed header and body and within the body is a main DIV.

For the page to change, the contents of the main DIV is changed. (Not my development)

I would like to display a notice to the user (Please wait loading) for any DB requests to the server or if the page changes. (The contents of the main DIV is changed for this to occur). Once the results from the DB has been returned or the main DIV has completed loading, I would like for the notice to be removed.

I am considering using JQuery to achieve this, by having a loader DIV within the body and for this to be visible when required and hidden when not.

What would be the best JQuery function to use to achieve my requirements?

There is no AJAX used on the site.

Many thanks

Comment: Could you tell me the magic of not doing AJAX and still doing a DB query? I want to know!

Comment: I think he probably is referring to Ajax as the MS specific implementation. Obviously you're going to have to use some kind of Ajax for what he's doing here...

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for `.show()` and `.hide()`  Or, if you want to get fancy, `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()`

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudo-code:

```
$(document).ready
(
    function()
    {
        $("#cmdQuery").click
        (
            function()
            {
                setProgressMessage();
                executeQuery();
            }
        );
    }
);

function setProgressMessage()
{
    // show query in progress message
}

function closeProgressMessage()
{
    // close query in progress message
}

function executeQuery()
{
    serverQuery(localCallBackFunction);
}

function localCallBackFunction(result)
{
    // process result of query
    closeProgressMessage();
}

<input type="button" id="cmdQuery" Text="Execute Query" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my all favorite bookmark on how to create a jQuery ajax webpage:

http://www.queness.com/post/328/a-simple-ajax-driven-website-with-jqueryphp